# Python Taking Multiple User Input from a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm making multiple user input from the class called Employee. My task is that I need to input at least 6 employees and print them all at once. What should be done to fix the problem?

```
`class Employee:

    def __init__ (self, number, first, middle, last, address, rate, salary):
        self.number = number
        self.first = first
        self.middle = middle
        self.last = last
        self.address = address
        self.rate = rate
        self.salary = rate*28


    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format("Empoloyee Number: " + self.number + "\n",
                                                "First Name: " + self.first +"\n",
                                                "Middle Name: " + self.middle + "\n",
                                                "Last Name: "+ self.last + "\n",
                                                "Address: " + self.address + "\n Rate: ",
                                                self.rate,
                                                "\n Salary: ", self.salary)


i=1
while i <7:
    number = input("Enter Employee Number: ")
    first = input("Enter First Name: ")
    middle = input("Enter Middle Name: ")
    last = input("Enter Last Name: ")
    address = input("Enter Address: ")
    rate = float(input("Enter Rate: "))

    salary = rate*28

   emp = (Employee(number, first, middle, last, address, rate, salary))
   print (emp.fullname())
   i+=1

`
```

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) Decide for one Python version and remove the other tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to append each employee you create, to a list, and then print the list after you have appended all 6.

```
def __init__ (self, number, first, middle, last, address, rate, salary):
    self.number = number
    self.first = first
    self.middle = middle
    self.last = last
    self.address = address
    self.rate = rate
    self.salary = rate*28


def fullname(self):
    return '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format("Empoloyee Number: " + self.number + "\n",
                                            "First Name: " + self.first +"\n",
                                            "Middle Name: " + self.middle + "\n",
                                            "Last Name: "+ self.last + "\n",
                                            "Address: " + self.address + "\n Rate: ",
                                            self.rate,
                                            "\n Salary: ", self.salary)


employees = []

i=1
while i<=6:
    number = input("Enter Employee Number: ")
    first = input("Enter First Name: ")
    middle = input("Enter Middle Name: ")
    last = input("Enter Last Name: ")
    address = input("Enter Address: ")
    rate = float(input("Enter Rate: "))

    salary = rate*28

    emp = Employee(number, first, middle, last, address, rate, salary))
    employees.append(emp)

print(employees)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how to show all the output of all my inputs which are not the unique addresses? From the results, I only get the output of the unique addresses of my inputs such as [<__main__.Employee object at 0x00000186E1212950>, <__main__.Employee object at 0x00000186E1212AD0>, <__main__.Employee object at 0x00000186E1212C50>].